Is it possible to validate a 'Key' while installing a npm package?
I am building a npm package and I want it to be available to only to clients who have availed a subscription plan. A user gets a Secret Key when they the payment is completed. The package prompts for the key. If the key is correct, the rest of the installation proceeds as expected.
Is it possible to make a request to the database to validate the key during installation? If yes, is there any potential risks involved?
